# Socket operation on non socket error in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am new to socket programming... I tried  this server side program

```
#define BUFLEN 512
#define MYPORT 3456
void errorp(char* msg)
{
        perror(msg);
        exit(1);
}

int main()
{
        struct sockaddr_in server, client;
        int sock;
        int slen = sizeof(server);
        int clen = sizeof(client);
        char *recvbuf, senbuf[BUFLEN] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};

        if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) == -1))
                errorp("Socket creation failed");


        printf("To the client: %s, %s", senbuf, " World");
        bzero(&server, sizeof(server));

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = MYPORT;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, slen)==-1)
                errorp("Socket Bind Failed");
        if(recvfrom(sock, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &clen) == -1)
                errorp("recv from error");
        printf("From the client: %s", recvbuf);

        if(sendto(sock, senbuf, sizeof(senbuf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, sizeof(client)) == -1)
                errorp("Error in sending");

        printf("To the client: %s", senbuf);
        close(sock);
        return 0;
}
```

There are no compilation errors but the output is

```
Socket Bind Failed: Socket operation on non-socket
To the client: hello,  World
```

Please help me figure out where the mistake is?
and help get rid of it

Comment: Side note: the port number has to be converted to network byte order: `server.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);` .

Comment: "*There are no compilation errors ...*" but there are warnings at least if you'd compiled using the options `-Wal -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: `-Wal` should have read `-Wall`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error message says it all: The socket isn't a (valid) socket.

This should make you look at the code creating the socket:

```
if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) == -1))
```

The code above 1st compares the result of the call to `socket()` to `-1` and then assigns the result of the comparison to `sock`. So it's either `0` or `1`. And the result of the call to `socket()` is lost.

The code shall look like this:

```
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
```

as `==` binds tighter then `=`.

---

BTW, having used a [*Yoda-Conditition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) would have avoided such kind of "typo":

```
if (-1 == (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
```

---

Also at least `clen` shall be of type `socklen_t` as its address is passed, to have a value written into it, which will fail miserably if the size of the expected `socklen_t` would be different from an `int`  (which the code shown passes).

Comment: Well spotted.  And once that's fixed, the next fatal error is UB because recvbuf is used uninitialized.

Comment: @JohnZwinck But i din't get any such errors.. cud you explain wat UB is?

Comment: @PrathapB: undefined behavior.  Your recvbuf is garbage.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: "*Your recvbuf is garbage.*" it isn't at all! ;-)

Comment: @PrathapB: You might like to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/694576

Comment: It's an uninitialized pointer, ie. garbage, as described by @JohnZwinck.  The there's 'sizeof(recvbuf)' - gonna be 4 or 8. Even if you malloc recvbuf, 'printf("From the client: %s", recvbuf)' will likely blow up if the datagram is not null-terminated.

Answer (score 10):

```
if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) == -1))
//         \__________________________________/
```

You have your brackets in the wrong place. It's setting `sock` to a true/false value because `==` is "more binding" than `=`. It should instead be:

```
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
//  \_____________________________________/
```

which sets `sock` to the return value from `socket()` and *then* compares that to `-1`.

You also have no backing storage for `recvbuf` which means your `recvfrom()`, once it starts working, will almost certainly do something bad.